Plugging in an external USB disk gives me one name (sdr), but trying to mount the filesystem on it fails with different name (sdq)
I use a USB external hard drive to back up my home directory. The device is configured as an LVM device with a volume group named homevg and a volume named home that contains an XFS filesystem. When I plug in the drive, device /dev/sdr is created and, running various commands, I get the following:
# lsblk
...
sdr                   65:16   0 698.6G  0 disk 

# pvs -a
...
  /dev/sdr   homevg      lvm2 a--   698.63g <349.32g

# pvscan
...
  PV /dev/sdr    VG homevg        lvm2 [698.63 GiB / <349.32 GiB free]

# lvs -a
...
  home     homevg      -wi-a----- <349.32g                                                    

# lvscan
...
  ACTIVE            '/dev/homevg/home' [<349.32 GiB] inherit

This all looks good to me, but when I try to mount the filesystem, I get an error:
# mount /dev/homevg/home /mnt
mount: /mnt: can't read superblock on /dev/mapper/homevg-home.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

and dmesg says:
# dmesg
...
[906061.599821] usb 4-4.1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[906061.612680] usb 4-4.1: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=1153, bcdDevice= 0.01
[906061.612698] usb 4-4.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[906061.612703] usb 4-4.1: Product: AS2115
[906061.612707] usb 4-4.1: Manufacturer: ASMedia
[906061.612710] usb 4-4.1: SerialNumber: 00000000000000000000
[906061.614744] usb-storage 4-4.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[906061.615354] scsi host18: usb-storage 4-4.1:1.0
[906062.636538] scsi 18:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ASMT     2115             0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[906062.637205] sd 18:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg18 type 0
[906062.638817] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdr] Spinning up disk...
[906063.659796] ..ready
[906064.737399] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdr] 1465149168 512-byte logical blocks: (750 GB/699 GiB)
[906064.737859] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdr] Write Protect is off
[906064.737868] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdr] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[906064.738200] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdr] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[906064.741734] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdr] Attached SCSI disk
[906114.612477] mount: attempt to access beyond end of device
                sdq: rw=524288, sector=732571520, nr_sectors = 8 limit=0
[906114.612492] mount: attempt to access beyond end of device
                sdq: rw=0, sector=732571520, nr_sectors = 8 limit=0
[906114.612497] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-11, logical block 91571184, async page read
[906114.612760] mount: attempt to access beyond end of device
                sdq: rw=4096, sector=2050, nr_sectors = 2 limit=0
[906114.612767] EXT4-fs (dm-11): unable to read superblock
[907040.271479] block dm-11: the capability attribute has been deprecated.

So sdr is attached successfully, but then mount is looking at sdq (/dev/sdq does not show up when I do ls /dev or ls /sys/block), and fails trying to find an ext4 superblock.
This is the second time in about a month that I've had this problem and I've succeeded in backing up my home directory at least twice [1] since the last time it happened. Last time that this happened, I rebooted and everything worked fine afterwards. I'm about to try a reboot again and see if that clears it up this time as well - I'll update the question afterwards with status.
Distro: Fedora 40
Kernel: 6.10.4-200.fc40.x86_64

Can somebody explain to me what is going on and perhaps how I can avoid this problem in the future?
UPDATE: after a reboot, everything worked fine: /dev/sdq was created when I plugged in the disk and mount /dev/homevg/home /mnt succeeded. Here's the dmesg output:
...
[  149.593238] usb 4-4.1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  149.606098] usb 4-4.1: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=1153, bcdDevice= 0.01
[  149.606109] usb 4-4.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  149.606113] usb 4-4.1: Product: AS2115
[  149.606117] usb 4-4.1: Manufacturer: ASMedia
[  149.606133] usb 4-4.1: SerialNumber: 00000000000000000000
[  149.607487] usb-storage 4-4.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  149.607933] scsi host17: usb-storage 4-4.1:1.0
[  150.642869] scsi 17:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ASMT     2115             0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  150.643432] sd 17:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg18 type 0
[  150.645024] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdq] Spinning up disk...
[  151.666190] ..ready
[  152.744416] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdq] 1465149168 512-byte logical blocks: (750 GB/699 GiB)
[  152.744743] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdq] Write Protect is off
[  152.744748] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdq] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  152.745061] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdq] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  152.748500] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdq] Attached SCSI disk
[  193.323364] XFS (dm-11): Mounting V5 Filesystem 8d2cc834-be33-43db-a6c0-31f1c1f99700
[  194.423760] XFS (dm-11): Ending clean mount


UPDATE 2: After I unmount the filesystem and I unplug the disk, if I try to plug it in again, I end up with the problem: /dev/sdr is the device, but mount is still looking for sdq (I was probably mistaken when I said above that I had successfully backed up at least twice: that does not seem possible in the light of this).

Footnote:
[1] This is probably wrong: I must have made up the "twice". See UPDATE 2 above.
